# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to do the following but my when i go to add the content to the table it crashes. with this error:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier UtilityTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

```
import UIKit

class UtilityBillTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var bills = [UtilityBill]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return bills.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "UtilityTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UtilityTableViewCell

        let bill = bills[indexPath.row]

        cell.billName.text = bill.billName
        cell.totalDue.text = bill.amountDue
        cell.totalDue.text = bill.dueDate


        return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }

    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    @IBAction func unwindToBillList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? UtilitiesViewController, let bill = sourceViewController.bill {
            // Add a new meal item.

            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: bills.count, section: 0)
            bills.append(bill)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clue!!!!!! The cellIdentifier vairable didnt match the actual name of the Identifier in the Attributes Inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've defined cell in storyboard, you have to specify that reuse identifier in the prototype cell in that storyboard scene; if you're using NIB or custom class, you have to register it.

You should double check the spelling for your cell identifier in the storyboard's prototype cell. Or if using NIB or programmatically created cell, make sure to call the appropriate register method.